# How can we get OLD data each time we subscribe observable in angular?

Tags: angular

Recently I come to this requirement where I subscribing observable 3 times in 3 different for loop.

I am getting updated data each time.
How can we get OLD data each time we subscribe observable in angular?

Comment: You want to keep the history of your data?

Comment: do you have control over the server/database? It is bad practice to make service calls in a for loop, and should be avoided. you should send in a list of id's that you want in one service call, and then have one subscription to parse through it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) that "Replays" or emits old values to new subscribers:

> A variant of Subject that "replays" or emits old values to new
>   subscribers. It buffers a set number of values and will emit those
>   values immediately to any new subscribers in addition to emitting new
>   values to existing subscribers.

```js
import * as Rx from "rxjs";

const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(2);

// subscriber 1
subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber A:', data);
});

subject.next(Math.random())
subject.next(Math.random())
subject.next(Math.random())

// subscriber 2
subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber B:', data);
});

subject.next(Math.random());

// Subscriber A: 0.3541746356538569
// Subscriber A: 0.12137498878080955
// Subscriber A: 0.531935186034298
// Subscriber B: 0.12137498878080955
// Subscriber B: 0.531935186034298
// Subscriber A: 0.6664809293975393
// Subscriber B: 0.6664809293975393
```

Code source: [Understanding rxjs BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject and AsyncSubject](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use service property or component property for this.
If you want to keep your data local to component then go with one property and keep pushing the received data in that property in **next** callback. On the other hand if you want to **share data/logic** with another component then go with service with same approach of pushing data and just inject service into another component where you want to use it.(don't forget to use same instance of service)
[Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep track of the old values yourself, as Angular doesn't provide a way to get at those old values. Here's some sample code showing one way of doing this.

```
@Component(...)
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private dataService){   }

    private oldData;

    ngOnInit(){
       this.dataService.getSomeData().subscribe((data)=>{
          if(this.oldData){
             //do stuff with old data. 
             //Not available until the SECOND time this callback is called
          }
          this.oldData = data;

          //do stuff with new data
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bron. That was really helpful. But i was looking solution for situation like suppose, I have 3 loops in same function subscribing same observable one after another. How second and third loop get the data from starting where first loop read the observable till the end?

Comment: Without seeing your code, this will be very hard to answer. If you update your question to include a sample of your code, we can much more easily attempt to answer your question.

Comment: i wasn't doing any coding with this actually. This was the i asked in one of the Interview.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish what you asked, but you could probably keep an array of old data from subscriptions based off of some key from your loop indexes